# Using the euclidean algorithm to find the inverse of $50 \mod 3$

Tags: number-theory

To solve a congruency like

$$50x \equiv 17 \mod3$$

You need to find the inverse of

$$50x \mod 3$$

For this, you have to write $1$ as a linear combination of $50$ and $3$:

$$1 = 50k_1+3k_2$$

Good, now how do I find $k_1$ and $k_2$... Well, the paper says that to do so, I must

> Use the Euclidean algorithm. Hence:
>
> $$1 = 3 – 2*1\\ 1 = 3 - (50 – 3*16)*1 = 3(1+16) + 50*(-1) = 3*17 -1*50$$

Now, now. I know how to do that algorithm to find the greatest common divisor. I also know that such value for $50$ and $3$ should be $1$ so that they can have an inverse.

But that's it. I don't know how to "use" the Euclidean algorithm to "solve" the congruency. I know the steps to the algorithm and yet do not understand what did they do in the quote above. Could you clarify?

Comment: I'll admit I didn't read your post (and thus, this comment is worthless), but you're working way too hard! Reduce everything mod 3 first to get $2x \equiv 2 \mod 3$.

Comment: You want to find the inverse of 50 mod 3 (so that you can multiply both side of your congruence by it and cancel the 50 on the LHS), not "$50x$".  This would involve the Algorithm applied to 50 and 3, which gives as a first step: $50 = 16*3 +2$, which I don't see in your work.

Answer (score 1):

We have shown that:
$$
(3)(17) + (-1)(50) = 1
$$
Now find the remainder of both sides modulo $3$. This makes the seventeen $3$'s vanish to get:
$$
(-1)(50) \equiv 1 \pmod 3
$$
Thus, we conclude that the inverse of $50$ (modulo $3$) is $-1$. Multiplying both sides of the original problem by this inverse yields:
\begin{align*}
(-1)(50)x &\equiv (-1)17 \pmod 3 \\
(1)x &\equiv -17 \pmod 3 \\
x &\equiv 1 \pmod 3 \\
\end{align*}